# How do I make regex properly validate the information?

Tags: c#, regex, validation, textbox

I've been given the task to make a textbox where you enter your personal code (something we in Latvia use). I need it to be validated before saving the information. For validation I've been using Regex but so far got no result.

Our personal code is like this : XXYYZZ-ABCDE, where
XXYYZZ is date format as in DAYMONTHYEAR and ABCDE are random numbers.

```
        if (per_kods.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
            mRegxExpression = new Regex("${day}-${month}-${year}-#####$");

            if (!mRegxExpression.IsMatch(per_kods.Text.Trim()))
            {
                label7.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                label7.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label7.Text = "Personas kods ievadīts nepareizi!";
                pareizi = false;
            }
        }
```

this currently is my code. It basically enables a label above the textbox pointing out that the information entered is wrong. If the information is right, the label continues to be disabled. But right now the new Regex part is a problem. I know it might seem totally wrong, but I've just started learning Regex and don't know what's wrong and what's right.

Comment: Can you please show valid (and invalid) inputs?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/BMFTgYq.png   Valid part has the code written correctly, so no label is being enabled. Invalid part has the code wrong, because I've typed 24 month which is false. The MessageBox shows up when there are no labels enabled, but there should've been since the personal code isn't written correctly, but my regex doesn't see it as incorrect so it doesn't enable the ''if'' that enables the label to signal that it's wrong.

Comment: Please add the information as text, not as a screenshot. If I understand C# correctly, the Regex class ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2 ) takes standard regex syntax. So you need `^[0123]\d[01]\d\d\d-[A-Z]{5}$` for validation.

Comment: I know it an old topic, but they stopped using dates in the first part of the code.And the last digit is a checksum

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about date validation (so for example 31st of February will be accepted, you can do

```
new Regex(@"^(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\d{2})-(\d{5})$");
```

If you want to understand what this string means, take a look at [the MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Now for date validation, so filtering out dates like `310298` that don't exist, I'd recommend you do it manually afterwards - regex is not the best tool for such logic-validation.

EDIT:

You can accomplish that using `DateTime.TryParse`.

```
DateTime resultDateTime;

var isValid = DateTime.TryParse(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", 2010, 2, 31), out resultDateTime);

// isValid is false, because 31st of February 2010 does not exist.

var isValid = DateTime.TryParse(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", 2010, 2, 27), out resultDateTime);

// isValid is true, and resultDateTime has been set to 27-2-2010.
```

Note that `DateTime.TryParse` is culture sensitive. Depending on the target culture you might need to change the input string. See [MSDN reference for `TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2).

EDIT2:

So to connect this with your existing code:

```
mRegxExpression = new Regex(@"^(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\d{2})-(\d{5})$");

var match = mRegxExpression.Match(per_kods.Text.Trim()));

if(!Validate(match))
{
    // Handle invalid.
}
else
{
    // Handle valid.
}
```

Where `Validate` would be:

```
private static bool Validate(Match match)
{
    if(!match.Success)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var day = match.Groups[1].ToString();
    var month = match.Groups[2].ToString();
    var year = match.Groups[3].ToString();

    return DateTime.TryParse($"{day}-{month}-{year}", out _);
}
```

Because our regex begins with `^` and ends with `$`, there will be always at most one match. The `Success` property tells us whether there was any match at all, and later the `Groups` property gives us the capture groups. `Groups[0]` will be the entire matched string, and then every next one will be the substring that matches one of the parentheses enclosed groups from regex - so the first one is `(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])` which represents days, the second will be months, and so on. Then we just check if the date is valid (again, culture sensitive!). Also, we can neatly use the C#7 discard syntax (`_`) for the `out` parameter, as we don't need it.

Comment: what is the best tool for such logic-validation? EDIT: for some reason my code doesn't understand the \d in that line.

Comment: I edited the answer to include using `DateTime.TryParse`.
And yes, I forgot the `@` verbatim modifier before the regex, edited it as well.

Comment: Any chance you could show me how to connect this to the code I have already written?

Comment: It says the name '_' does not exist in current context at DateTime.TryParse($"{day}-{month}-{year}", out _);

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling with C# 7.0 features enabled?

Comment: how can I check?

Comment: If you're using VisualStudio see here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St

Comment: I changed it to C# 6.0

Comment: But that's a C# 7.0 feature. Change it to 7.0 or higher.

Comment: 6.0 is the highest I have.

Comment: Then you will have to provide a dummy `DateTime` object. Declare a `DateTime dt` and put `out dt` in place of the `out _`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from the code below to check validation.

```
public bool CheckValidation(string input)
    {
        input = input.Trim();
        if (input == string.Empty) return false;

        var mRegxExpression = new Regex("^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))\\d{2}(\\-)\\d{5}$");
        return mRegxExpression.IsMatch(input);

    }
```